# NOT IN scenario in Crystal Report with multiple datasources

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, select-query

I need to do the following select for my Crystal Report:

```
Select * from Table1 where ID not in (select ID from Table2 where mydate = @param)
```

And to make things more complicated Table 1 & Table 2 are on two different servers (one is Access, one is SQL on different machines).

I've tried several things, but can't seem to get the correct records.  I've tried using a left join, but of course I cannot filter on date.  Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to create formula for each field:

@Field1

If Table1.ID != Table2.ID

Then

Table1.Field1

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your answer, this will not give the correct resultset.  This would be the equivalent of 

Select * from Table1, Table2 where Table1.ID <> Table2

Answer (score 0):

ok since you have only 2 datasources try this:

Take main report and one sub report in that main report

Main report:

This query should be used in main report

```
select ID from Table2 where mydate = @param
```

Create a paramter and retrive the values in main report.

Now take sub report

sub report:

Sub report should use this query:

```
Select * from Table1
```

Now in record selection of sub report write this

```
ID not in ({?pm-ID})
```

`pm-ID}`is the value that you are passing from main report to sub report through sub report links

Now you can display data in report as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something (entirely possible), this should be doable using a left join.

For this illustration, I am using two SQL commands, there are records in table1 that are not in table2 and there are records in table 2 that are not in table1.

Records are only returned if table2 is null, or table2 is NOT null AND table2.Date is NOT equal to the parameter

When @param = '20160303', we don't see that record from table1 or table2.  **(ID 55)**
[image]

**Dataset example:** 
[image]

**Join:**

[image]

**RecordSelect Formula** 
[image]

To summarize: Setup the data sources using a left join on the common column.
Create a date parameter
Use Report > Select Export > Record and enter the following formula

```
isnull({Table2.date})or {Table2.date} <> {?date}
```

If you are using a date range, you may have to reformat the `not equal to @param` part